# Можно ли скомпилировать все файлы проекта в единственный .exe?

Tags: visual-studio, exe

Есть проект, в котором использую библиотеку `Newtonsoft`. В `bin\Release` соотвественно кроме основного `.exe` лежат бинарник библиотеки и файлы настроек. Можно ли собрать все это в один `.exe` средствами `Visual Studio`?

Comment: можно всё. а зачем? В чём удобство то? По сути будет происходить равно такая же распаковка. Если надо распространять - лучше использовать архив или установочник.

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно установить пакет MSBuild.ILMerge.Task из nuget.

Вот тут больше способов: [How to Integrate ILMerge into Visual Studio Build Process to Merge Assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2556048/4340086)

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать, с помощью утилиты ILMerge от Microsoft. Её можно скачать в даунлоад-центре Майкрософт, или с помощью NuGet, есть она и на ГитХабе.

В события построения проекта добавить в `Командная строка события "после построения"`

```
Ilmerge your.exe thirdparty.dll /out=merged.exe
```

Comment: Ответ неполный без упоминания где найти ILMerge. Это же не стандартная утилита...